# React - When to use stateless components and how to organize files

Tags: reactjs

So I have this project I working on:

A single page showing list of Movies.

So I have the `App.js`, this is currently my only Stateful-Component.

And I made this components:

- App.js - simply show the `<Movies />` component with proper attirubtes as will be explained in the next bullets.
- Movies ( list of movies ) - this component loop over the entire movies that given to him using props, and in each iteration we create `Movie` ( not plural ) component.
- Movie - In this component I show title, description and an option to delete this movie, and since `App.js` is the only stateful component, once you do "onClick" on that movie, it direct to the parent component `Movies` which directs to the `App.js` to active an deletion handler.
- One more component inside movie is `Description` which has the ability to expand text or show less text, once again it direct to `Movie` that direct to `Movies` that direct to `App.js` so it could active a
- Two more components are `Tags` that simply loop over `Tag` inside.

Now my questions are:

1. How to organize this files? I currently use this architecture:

```
src
-- Movies
    |-- Movie
    |   |-- Description
    |   |   --- Description.jsx
    |   |-- Tags
    |   |   |-- Tag
    |   |   |   --- Tag.jsx
    |   |   --- Tags.jsx
    |   --- Movie.jsx
    --- Movies.jsx
-- App.jsx
```

Is that too much components? should I merge for example `Tags` and `Tag`?

Is this nested folders is good? or should I just use a folder named `components` and puts there everything?

2. Is that make sense that only `App.jsx` has stateful component? because in my opinion every component that needs to be changed, for example the `Description` should has its own state whether he has full text shown or not. But I've seen on the internet that people say using a lot of stateful component will make the code more difficult to maintain.

I can see on the internet many different explanation with no one single truth, and I'll be very happy if someone could explain to me these principles.

Answer (score 1):

This is where react lacks, it is up to you how you organize your project, with proper experience you can create an awesome structure, but on the other hand, you could create an completely mess.

It will also depend on what libraries you are using, for instance: graphql, redux-saga, redux-thunk, or just redux, for which you will create another structure of files and folders.

I recommend you to investigate different approeaches and choose the one that fit your necessities, which will probably in different projects.

I will share you some posts I found useful when I had the same question as you:

- [How to better organize your React applications?](https://medium.com/@alexmngn/how-to-better-organize-your-react-applications-2fd3ea1920f1)
- [Optimal file structure for React applications](https://medium.com/@Charles_Stover/optimal-file-structure-for-react-applications-f3e35ad0a145)
- [Structuring projects and naming components in React](https://medium.com/hackernoon/structuring-projects-and-naming-components-in-react-1261b6e18d76)

**A the end I chose to treat my components as features and group them that way, for instance**

```
src
├─ components 
│  ├─ User
│  │ ├─ Form
│  │ │ ├─ Form.jsx
│  │ │ └─ Form.css
│  │ │ └─ index.js
│  │ └─ List.jsx
│  │ └─ index.js
│  └─ UI 
│  redux
|  └─ actions
|  └─ middlewares
|  └─ reduces
└─ screens
  ├─ User
  │ ├─ Form.jsx
  │ └─ List.jsx
  └─ Root.jsx
```

Comment: Thanks! what about the stateful components?